# How can powershell not end up in powershell's path?

Tags: windows, powershell

On one computer, otherwise working fine, there's a strange problem:
You can only execute PowerShell from places like the Start Menu, Run dialogue, Explorer .lnk; but you can't execute PowerShell form within PowerShell.

PowerShell is in `$env:path`, yet the result still is:

```
PS C:\Users\Laptop> powershell
powershell : The term 'powershell' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify tha
t the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ powershell
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (powershell:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I ran `sfc` and `dism` with no results. What is possibly wrong with the system that PowerShell can't find itself?

Comment: I don't think Powershell is meant to load itself. PS means you are operating PowerShell.

Comment: i presume this is in the `powershell.exe` shell, not the ISE. you get a different error there. [*grin*] what do you get form this >>> `($env:path -split ';').Where({$_ -match 'powershell'})` <<< while in the `powershell.exe` console on the problem box? you may have a glitched item in the path. for instance, i have `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\` 1st in that list ... but i cannot use it to run `Get-ChildItem` since the `%` markers are not legit for powershell. the 2nd item shows the full path & works properly.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I have _only_ `%SYSTEMROOT\System32\Wind...` in the list, I thought about the %% being cmd-only. Executing the powershell.exe from the mentioned dir (`C:\Windows\...`) works.
It's probably that I'm missing `C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` (as seen on one other computer).
I have now lived on Linux more than I have on Windows, how do I add the `C:\WINDOWS` env variable permanently to `$env:path` (can be posted as an answer) (and what caused this behaviour on an otherwise normal system)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8788828 It can be done with `setx PATH "$env:path;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\" -m`, you may post an answer to get the rep.

Comment: @u15p7fgy863eiq5 - kool! glad to know that you found and fixed the glitch! i presume that one of your installs somehow munged the `path` variable. thanks for posting the info! [*grin*]

Comment: If you run `$PSVersionTable` in PS, what is the PSVersion you are running.